# What's the meaning of "order page two"?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie, *Bombshell (2019)* Megyn speaks about his Fox news CEO, Roger:

> Megyn: Roger is also fat because he'll get a room-service menu and
> **order page two**. But he cares a lot about looks.

What's the meaning of "order page two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He will order all the food on page 2"

This is (probably) and exaggeration and hyberbole.

It is not clear why she says "page 2" and not "Page 1" or "page 3". Perhaps "Page 1" is for starters, or breakfast, but page 2 is main courses.  Or perhaps page 2 is for desserts.  Or perhaps page 2 is drinks.  This is not a standard expression.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context I would interpret the phrase **"order page two"** as the ordering of all the dishes on page 2.

As this is also the cause of its fatness I suppose page 2 is really full of dishes (or anyway there are many).

As James K said, the sentence is an exaggeration and hyberbole.